# Aeson error building test yesod-sqlite project

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I'm new to yesod and just trying to use stack to build one or two basic sites from the templates but I get an Aeson error when I do. There is a discussion of the error message here [0] but it is apparently fixed in 1.6.1 and I'm using 1.6.3. This is what I'm trying:

```
$ stack --version
Version 1.6.3
$ stack new yesod-project yesod-sqlite
Downloading template "yesod-sqlite" to create project "yesod-project" in    yesod-project/ ...
Looking for .cabal or package.yaml files to use to init the project.
Using cabal packages:
- yesod-project/

Selecting the best among 12 snapshots...

* Matches lts-10.5

Selected resolver: lts-10.5
Initialising configuration using resolver: lts-10.5
Total number of user packages considered: 1
Writing configuration to file: yesod-project/stack.yaml
All done.
$ cd yesod-project/
$ stack build
$ stack exec -- yesod devel
Yesod devel server. Enter 'quit' or hit Ctrl-C to quit.
Application can be accessed at:

http://localhost:3000
https://localhost:3443
If you wish to test https capabilities, you should set the following variable:
export APPROOT=https://localhost:3443

Downloading lts-10.5 build plan ...
Downloaded lts-10.5 build plan.
AesonException "Error in $.packages.cassava.constraints.flags['bytestring--lt-0_10_4']: Invalid flag   name: \"bytestring--lt-0_10_4\""
Type help for available commands. Press enter to force a rebuild.
```

[0] https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3634

Answer (score 3):

If you run `stack exec -- stack --version` I bet you will find that it is older than 1.6.3.  You should probably delete the stack binary at `stack exec -- which stack`

Answer (score 2):

mgsloan's assessment of the cause is correct, at least in my case.

Solution-wise, I'm guessing deleting the stack binary forces it to upgrade. For those who are hesitant to delete stack, `stack upgrade` did the trick for me.